# Unable to ssh from one AWS EC2 instance to another in the same VPC. Works from local

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2

Hi I have setup an EC2 Ubuntu instance (A) for use with additional [key-pair](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/replacing-key-pair.html).
Reason is that I need to connect with **myuser** to A instead of default user ubuntu.

1. Got the new pem file from `EC2>Network & Security>Key Pairs` console.
2. Created public key and added to *~/.ssh/config* for my user **myuser** on A.
3. Configured inbound rules for the A's security group allowing my local box (ipv4) to A.
4. Verified that I am able to login from my local box to A successfully.

I repeated the same configuration (3-4) for connecting from another EC2 instance (B).
I am seeing a connection timeout. Here's the verbose log.

```
OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.4, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/ubuntu/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname xxx.xx.xx.xxx is address
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/home/ubuntu/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/home/ubuntu/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to xxx.xx.xx.xxx [xxx.xx.xx.xxx] port 22.
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x10
debug1: connect to address xxx.xx.xxx.xx port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host xxx.xx.xx.xx port 22: Connection timed out
```

Checking this decently [detailed help page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstancesConnecting.html)
Particularly verified internet gateway, routing tables and ACL settings.
All seem to be in place.
Appreciate any help to debug this further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue with outbound rules on machine A. The ssh port 22 was not open.